# Tag Manager YouTube progress trigger continues after iFrame removed from DOM

Tags: youtube-api, google-tag-manager

I have a number of YouTube videos that are lazy loaded in a modal. The iFrames are generated when the modal is opened and destroyed when the modal closes. GTM Tracking is working with the youtube iFrame API enabled and default GTM YouTube triggers for start, stop, and progress.

However, I've noticed that if a user starts a video and closes the modal without implicitly stopping or pausing the video first, the progress triggers continue to fire even though the iFrame is no longer in the DOM. Basically, every video tracks to 100% playback even though you can't hear or see it.

I've tried using the iFrame API to stop or pause the video on close, but that doesn't seem to fix it. I've also called destroy() on the player instance in the API with no luck, probably due to it being my copy of the player and not GTM's.

Also, a side note, because the iFrame API uses a global method call for onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(), in order for both Tag Manager and my own code to work I had to capture Tag Manager's version and fire it inside my own version of the method. They should really change that to an event instead of a global method call so more than one script can use the API without killing the others.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved my own problem, but this seems to be a bug in either the YouTube API or the GTM built in trackers, not sure which.

Calling videoPause() and then waiting 500 milliseconds before destroying and removing the iframe does the trick.

Calling videoStop() even with the iframe still visible on page stops the playback but the percentage tracking keeps firing as if it was still playing. This seems like an issue.

Calling either and immediately destroying the player or removing the iFrame doesn't work at all. I guess it takes a tick to process the call and destroying interrupts that.

Comment: I can confirm that pausing video manually works. In my case it was not necessary to wait before destroying the iframe. To pause the video I queried the iframe element and then did the following: `iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');`

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I start a video in Angular using the youtube-player component, and the googletagmanager package. I see gtm.video event triggered on start but when I navigate away and destroy the component, the gtm.video keep firing on an interval.  I will try your solution, but def seems to be a bug